# Kafkastream springcloud kafka join selectKey

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

could you please help to configure a spring cloud stream app based on Kafka, I'm facing issue on the selectKey operation.

Let's explain what i m try to reach
2 incoming topics Person, RefGenre
Person contain the key of Refgenre (in value)

```
public class Person {
    String nom;
    String prenom;
    String codeGenre;  <<--- here is the key of the second topic refgenre 
}
```

So I m using the selectKey operator to prepare my stream before the join operation.

a new topic is created with selectByKey (my-app-KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000004-repartition), and then serialization issue happens :

*Exception in thread "my-app-3c57b31c-28e5-4199-b07d-87f8940425ab-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException while producing data to topic my-app-KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000004-repartition. A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: statefull.serde.PersonWithGenreSerde) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: statefull.model.Person). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters (for example if using the DSL, `#to(String topic, Produced<K, V> produced)` with `Produced.keySerde(WindowedSerdes.timeWindowedSerdeFrom(String.class))`).*

Where can i specify serde for this repartition topic and can i specify the name of this "internal" topic ?

```
@Bean
public BiFunction<KStream<String, Person>, KTable<String, ReferentielGenre>, KStream<Long, PersonWithGenre>> joinKtable() {
    return (persons, referentielGenres) ->
            persons.selectKey((k,v) -> v.getCodeGenre())
                .join(referentielGenres,
                (person, genre) -> new PersonWithGenre(person.getNom(), person.getPrenom(),genre),
                Joined.with(Serdes.String(), new PersonWithGenreSerde(), null));
```

}

here is the full code of my not working job : https://github.com/YohanAlard/joinkstream

Is there a better way to handle this usecase ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/GFdXWFW the topology

Comment: I think your last `join` call has some issues. In the `ValueJoiner` (second arg to `join`), the first arg is a `Person`, but you are passing in a `Serde` of type `PersonWithGenreSerde` that takes `PersonWithGenre` type. That needs to be a `Serde` that can handle `Person` types.

Comment: Thank you again ;) 
is there a way to name the repartition topic with the new key ? auto create topic is not allowed on our broker.  
Is there a better way to provide the same result without the cost of topic creation ?